# dojox.form.Uploader - Submit - doesn't reach the REST service from IE8

Tags: file-upload, internet-explorer-8, jersey, dojo

I'm trying to implement the dojox.form.Uploader in order to upload the files. I've created a simple REST service in JAVA.
From Firefox and Chrome, the service gets the form and saves the data, but this is not the case for IE8.

In IE8 I get totally different response object compared to what's fired in FF/Chr. It's actually an array with the file information, all with the 'error' - 'server time out' message. In fact, the form submission doesn't even hit the service.

I've just started with JAVA REST services so pardon any obvious errors.

Thanks heaps.
M.

client side code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Uploading test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/resources/dojo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/nihilo/nihilo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/form/resources/FileUploader.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/form/resources/UploaderFileList.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/form/resources/FileInput.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">djConfig = { parseOnLoad:true, isDebug:true, dojoBlankHtmlUrl: 'blank.html'  };</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
<script>
        dojo.require("dojox.form.Uploader");
        dojo.require("dojox.form.uploader.FileList");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.CheckBox");
        dojo.require("dojo.io.iframe");
        dojo.require("dojox.form.FileInput");
        dojo.require("dojox.form.uploader.plugins.Flash");
        dojo.require("dojox.form.uploader.plugins.HTML5");      

        function prepareForm(){
          var form = dojo.byId("myform");              

          // Disable the button at startup
          //dijit.byId('submitId').set("disabled", true);

          // Connect to the onChange event of file upload stuff.
          dojo.connect(dojo.byId("uploader"), "onchange", function(){ 
              //checkExtension();
          });

        // Connect to the onChange event of file upload stuff.
          dojo.connect(dijit.byId("uploader"), "onComplete", function(response){ 
              dojo.byId("response").innerHTML = "Form posted with status : " + response;
          });                        
        }
        dojo.ready(prepareForm);

    </script>
</head>
<body class="soria">
    <b>Simple Form:</b>
    <br>
    <form method="post" action="jersey/fileupload2" id="myForm"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <legend>file upload test</legend>
        <input name="uploadedfile" multiple="true" type="file" id="uploader"
            dojoType="dojox.form.Uploader" label="Select XLSX Files"
            style="width: 150px;">
        <div id="files" dojoType="dojox.form.uploader.FileList"
            uploaderId="uploader" style="width: 300px;"></div>
        <br /> <input type="submit" label="Submit"
            dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="submitId" />
    </form>
    <br>
    <b>Result</b>
    <div id="response"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

server side code

```
@Path("fileupload2")public class FileUploadResource2 {
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("text/html")
public String loadFile(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    String resultStatus="{response:'fail'}";
    String fileRepository="C:\\TEMP\\";     
    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) { 
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List<FileItem> items = null;
        try {           
            items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(items!=null) {
         Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();  
         while (iter.hasNext()) {  
             FileItem item = iter.next();                
             if(!item.isFormField() && item.getSize() > 0) {  
                     String fileName = processFileName(item.getName());
                     resultStatus="{response:'ok.'}";
                     try {
                        //throw new Exception("error happened.");
                        item.write(new File(fileRepository+fileName));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        resultStatus="{response:'failed.'}";
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                        //return "{result:'" + e.fillInStackTrace()  + "'}";                        
                    }  

             }               
         }  
        }           
     }
    return resultStatus;
}

private String processFileName(String fileNameInput) {
    String fileNameOutput=null;
    fileNameOutput = fileNameInput.substring(fileNameInput.lastIndexOf("\\")+1,fileNameInput.length());
    return fileNameOutput;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        String dir = getServletConfig().getInitParameter(
                "javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
        logger.info("FileUpload: doPost called, directory for the upload: "
                + dir);

        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        logger.info("Is multipart: " + isMultipart);

        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

        if (isMultipart) {

            // Create a new file upload handler
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
            // Parse the request
            FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);

            ArrayList<FileInfo> fileInfos = new ArrayList<FileInfo>();
            boolean html5 = false;

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItemStream item = iter.next();

                String name = item.getFieldName();
                InputStream stream = item.openStream();
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    logger.info("Form field " + name + " with value "
                            + Streams.asString(stream) + " detected.");
                } else {
                    logger.info("File field " + name + " with file name "
                            + item.getName() + " detected.");
                    if (name.contains("uploadedfiles"))
                        html5 = true;


                    // Process the input stream
                    File file = new File(dir + item.getName());
                    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(stream, file);

                    FileInfo e = new FileInfo();
                    e.setName(item.getName());
                    e.setFile(item.getName());
                    e.setExt(item.getContentType());

                    fileInfos.add(e);

                }

            }

            printJSON(out, html5, fileInfos);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void printJSON(ServletOutputStream out, boolean html5, ArrayList<FileInfo> fileInfos)
        throws IOException {
    if (!html5)
        out.print("<textarea>");
    out.print("[");

    for (FileInfo fileInfo : fileInfos) {
        out.print("{");
        out.print("\"name\": \"" + fileInfo.getName() + "\",");
        out.print("\"file\": \"" + fileInfo.getFile() + "\",");
        out.print("\"type\": \"" + fileInfo.getExt() + "\"");
        out.print("}");
    }

    out.print("]");
    if (!html5)
        out.print("</textarea>");
}
```

FileInfo is a simple class with following fields:

```
private String name;
private String file;
private String ext;
```